# Segmentation Fault in vkCmdBlitImage

Tags: nvidia, vulkan

There is a segmentation fault in `vkCmdBlitImage`. According to Valgrind, it is an invalid read of size 8 with the address being 0x48. Disabling layers does not fix the problem.

The driver used is the Nvidia Linux driver version 364.19. The GPU is a GeForce GTX 970.

Relevant code:

```
VkImageCreateInfo img_info;
img_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
img_info.pNext = NULL;
img_info.flags = 0;
img_info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
img_info.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
img_info.extent = (VkExtent3D){info.width, info.height, 1};
img_info.mipLevels = 1;
img_info.arrayLayers = 1;
img_info.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
img_info.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
img_info.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT;
img_info.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
img_info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
img_info.pQueueFamilyIndices = NULL;
img_info.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED;

VkImage src_image;
VKR(vkCreateImage(info.device, &img_info, NULL, &src_image));

VkMemoryRequirements src_req;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(info.device, src_image, &src_req);
VkDeviceMemory src_mem = create_memory(info.physical_device, info.device,
                                       src_req.memoryTypeBits, src_req.size,
                                       true); //The true makes it create host-visible memory.

vkBindImageMemory(info.device, src_image, src_mem, 0);

VkImageSubresource src_subres;
src_subres.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
src_subres.mipLevel = 0;
src_subres.arrayLayer = 0;

VkSubresourceLayout src_subres_layout;
vkGetImageSubresourceLayout(info.device, src_image, &src_subres, &src_subres_layout);

uint8_t* src_data = NULL;
VKR(vkMapMemory(info.device, src_mem, src_subres_layout.offset, src_subres_layout.rowPitch*info.height, 0, (void**)&src_data));

//Code that initialized src_data

VkMappedMemoryRange range;
range.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MAPPED_MEMORY_RANGE;
range.pNext = NULL;
range.memory = src_mem;
range.offset = src_subres_layout.offset;
range.size = src_subres_layout.rowPitch * info.height;
VKR(vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges(info.device, 1, &range));
vkUnmapMemory(info.device, src_mem);

VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo alloc_info;
alloc_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
alloc_info.pNext = NULL;
alloc_info.commandPool = info.cmd_pool;
alloc_info.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
alloc_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
VkCommandBuffer cmd_buf;
VKR(vkAllocateCommandBuffers(info.device, &alloc_info, &cmd_buf));

VkCommandBufferBeginInfo begin_cmd_buf_info;
begin_cmd_buf_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
begin_cmd_buf_info.pNext = NULL;
begin_cmd_buf_info.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
begin_cmd_buf_info.pInheritanceInfo = NULL;
vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmd_buf, &begin_cmd_buf_info);

image_barrier(VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, cmd_buf, VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT,
              VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED,
              VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
              VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, src_image);

image_barrier(VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, cmd_buf, info.dst_img_access,
              VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT, info.dst_img_layout,
              VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
              VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, info.dst_image);

VkImageBlit region;
region.srcSubresource = (VkImageSubresourceLayers){VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0, 1};
region.srcOffsets[0] = (VkOffset3D){0, 0, 0};
region.srcOffsets[1] = (VkOffset3D){info.width, info.height, 1};
region.dstSubresource = (VkImageSubresourceLayers){VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 0, 0, 1};
region.dstOffsets[0] = (VkOffset3D){0, 0, 0};
region.dstOffsets[1] = (VkOffset3D){info.width, info.height, 1};
vkCmdBlitImage(cmd_buf, src_image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, info.dst_image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region, VK_FILTER_NEAREST);

vkEndCommandBuffer(cmd_buf);
```

The rest of the code is found at https://gitlab.com/pendingchaos/WIP29/tree/00f348f2ef588e5f724fcb1f695e7692128cac4c/src.

Cut down output of vulkaninfo can be found at http://pastebin.com/JaHqCy98.

Comment: Why would you post the mostly-useless vulkaninfo dump, while hiding the actually useful information (the actual code) behind `gitlab` links?

Comment: @NicalBolas I posted the dump in case it would be useful. I will move the Gitlab links above the vulkaninfo dump.

Comment: I have further edited it so that some of the code is posted in the question and the dump is pasted on pastebin.com.

Comment: "*create_memory*" Please tell me you're *not* allocating device memory for each image/buffer you create.

Comment: @nicol-bolas I am doing that at the moment. Thanks for the input by the way.

Comment: @krOoze vkCmdBlitImage crashes. The question has been edited to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the input
I think the barriers are now correct (though it still segmentation faults)

Answer (score 0):

Your synchronization seems improper for the jorb. They discard your preinitialized Image and do no synchronization (due to the dst=BOTTOM).

Let me put together something that should work just fine with your computationaly demanding 4x4 Image processing:

```
image_barrier( VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, cmd_buf,
               VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT,
               VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, 
               VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
               src_image);

image_barrier( VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, cmd_buf,
               info.dst_img_access, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
               info.dst_img_layout, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
               VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
               info.dst_image);
```

BTW:

1. the `amount` should be `VkDeviceSize` not `size_t` in `createMemory()`
2. `vkBindImageMemory()`, `vkBeginCommandBuffer()` and `vkEndCommandBuffer()` return and should perhaps be in your `VKR`
3. If you rewrite whole aspect of the image, you can use `src=LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` to discard the old data (more efficient!)

Comment: Thanks but it still crashes